# Can I organize history with Dataset?

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm

I have a Dynamics CRM 365 (on-Prem). My users get data from it, save in Excel files and manually updates it in Power BI every month. I want to make their lives easier. 
So the question is: can I update Power BI dataset via IP? Basically adding new portion of data every month? Or maybe there is another convenient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use one of these approaches:

1. PowerBI should connect to Dynamics 365 data directly (either odata or SQL connection)
2. Or keep the monthly updated excel file in OneDrive to access from PowerBI directly

PowerBI got the dataset auto-refresh periodically (even on-prem using Enterprise gateway)

Comment: I want to walk away from files, so I decided to create history table in SQL and beg for storage space on SQL server. Thanks for advise.